# Advanced nested AND clause in Laravel 5 Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am having a hard time converting this query to laravel eloquent and any help will be well appreciated.

The query that I need to run is

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `id` <> 2 AND (`tags` LIKE '%tag1%' OR `tags` LIKE '%tag2%')
```

This is what I have now

```
$relatedArticles = Article::where('id', '<>', $article->id);
if (!is_null($article->tags)) {
    foreach (explode(',', $article->tags) as $tag) {

        $relatedArticles = $relatedArticles->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $tag . '%');
    }
}
$relatedArticles = $relatedArticles->get();
```

But the above code yields me

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `id` <> 2 OR `tags` LIKE '%tag1%' OR `tags` LIKE '%tag2%'
```

which is not what I am looking for.

Thanks

With Regards
Gagan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "advanced where". Instead of a column name you feed the `where` with a function. For more clarity look it up here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres. Your code should look like the one below:

```
$relatedArticles = Article::where('id', '<>', $article->id);

if (!is_null($article->tags)) {
    $relatedArticles->where(function($query) use ($article) {
        foreach (explode(',', $article->tags) as $tag) {
            $query->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $tag . '%');
        }
    });
}

$relatedArticles = $relatedArticles->get();
```

P.S. if you're wondering what `use` is, anonymous functions on PHP are not like on JavaScript, you need to specify the variables that would be visible on the function.

Comment: I am marking this as an answer. this is the same as the one  by Stuart Wagner, but I believe this was posted earlier. Sorry about that Stuart..

Comment: No worries. Happens all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's easy to convert that SQL in a Laravel query using the Query Builder syntax.

It would go like this:

```
$relatedArticles = Article::where('id', '<>', $article->id)
                            ->where(function($query)
                                   {
                                        $query->where(`tags`, 'like', '%tag1%')
                                              ->orWhere(`tags`, 'like', '%tag2%')
                                   });
```

More info on that: [Laravel Advanced Wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$relatedArticles = Article::where('id', '<>', $article->id);

if (!is_null($article->tags)) {
    $relatedArticles->where(function($query) use ($article)
    {
        foreach (explode(',', $article->tags) as $tag) {
            $query->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $tag . '%');
        }
    });
}

$relatedArticles->get();
```

More info on [advanced wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres).